# How to update single field with new data for multiple records

Tags: mysql

We have a table where the table consists of number of fields in that there is one field called **sector**. Inside the sector we have the value **office executive/office admin, IT support...**. For all the thousand records with different sector value, but now we want update the sector value of **office executive/office admin** to only **Office Admin**. Is there an option to update the entire thousand records in a single query with out using the ID?

This is my table structure

```
resume_id(Primary key), 
resume_title, 
language,
dob,
sector,
creation date
```

consider these values inside the table

```
+---+---------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 1 |  akash  |  english |  12-11-2001 |  IT support                    |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
| 2 |  vinay  |  english |  12-11-2001 |  office executive/office admin |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
| 3 |  Kumar  |  english |  12-11-2001 |  office executive/office admin |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
| 4 |  Denesh |  english |  12-11-2001 |  office executive/office admin |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
| 5 |  urs    |  english |  12-11-2001 |  office executive/office admin |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
| 6 |  vinay  |  english |  12-11-2001 |  IT Support                    |  2017-11-08 06:57:43  |
+---+---------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Like this we have many records here and I want to update only the sector value from office **executive/office** admin to **Office Admin** for all the records with a single query without using a primary key.

Comment: Can you please share the table(s) structure.

Comment: Please try to improve your question by adding some sample data, your table schema and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple update query for this

```
update table_name set sector = 'Office Admin'
where sector = 'office executive/office admin';
```